# Php makedir in the same root folder

Tags: php

Please am using this to create a new directory, but is invalid path when i want to create folder in the same directory and is showing Invalid path specified. But if i try to create in a different folder it will work.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['makejail'])){

$jailorgname = $_POST['jailName'];
$parentDir = '/';//cjl I want to create in the same root folder

if(!is_dir($parentDir)) { 
    echo('Invalid path specified');
}

else if(!is_writable($parentDir)) { 
    echo('Unable to create directory, permissions denied.');
}
else if(file_exists($parentDir."/".$jailorgname)){
    echo('Folder already exist');
}

else if(mkdir($parentDir."/".$jailorgname) === false) {
    echo('Problems creating directory.');
}
else{
echo "Folder was created";
}
}?>
```

Comment: `$parentDir = '/';` <-- that's wrong. `/` is the _root_ directory of the machine.

Comment: So how can i do it now? if i remove `$parentDir = '/';` it will show error @Here2Help

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `$parentDir` wrong:

```
$parentDir = '/';
```

This points to the *root* directory of the machine, not the parent directory of your script.

You may want to use the magic constant `__DIR__` like this:

```
$parentDir = __DIR__ . "/.."; // Go up one level from the current directory
```

See here for more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php